# Django Forms Help needed

Tags: django, django-forms

Im new to django and trying to make a user registration form with few validations.
Apart from this I also want a username suggestion code which will tell the user if the username he is trying to register is available or already in use. Then it should give few suggestions that might be available to choose from. Can anyone who might have worked on the same or somewhat same project help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I have just started getting a view with the field requirements....stuck on how to connect it to postgresql db....and get the data whn submit button is pressed...can u help...

Comment: You have posted exactly the same question twice:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719292/django-forms-help-needed/2729185

Maybe you show first read the Manual http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: yeah i know it has been posted twice. I apologise for that actually when i posted it first it didnt come up in the question section so I thot here would be a problem so I posted again. ;)
thnx for the reply tho..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this by [overriding the clean](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) method of the corresponding field in the form:

```
def clean_username(self):
    if 'username' in self.cleaned_data:
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        #DO YOUR CHECK
        if THERE_IS_ALREADY_SUCH_USERNAME:
            err = _(u'This username already exists. Try one of the following: %(sug)s)' % SUGGESTIONS)
            raise forms.ValidationError(err)
        return username
```

Comment: Hi aeby, Thanks for that post. I got that working now and now my django form is checking if the user already exists or not but can you help me writing some suggestion script...to check for few suggestions..hope u knw wat i mean....thankx