# django forms- register user script

Tags: database, django, django-forms, database-connection

I want to make something like 
http://www.djangosnippets.org/accounts/register/
using django..the register form.
I am new to django.
i have made a simple view form using django forms but unable o understand how to connect my form to a database. Im using postgresql. is there an easy way to use some snippet or script to achieve this.

Please Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719292/django-forms-help-needed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719452/django-forms-help-needed

I'd stick to asking just once...  try communicating with those who answer your questions and try to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Hi Thankx for that bitbucket link. It was a great help with only one problem. when an email is sent with the activaion key it doesnt activates the account. Can you help me fixing that.
Thanks

Comment: Hey its been fixed. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/.  This pretty much takes much of the guesswork out of user registration.  It even supports email verification and a few other advanced features.  If this isn't what you are looking for than perhaps the source code might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for that link....I got that working now... only stuck in figuring out how to extend the form with few more fields that i require a user to enter...will appreciate if you could help me with it..
Thanks.

Comment: Django calls that "user profiles" http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

DjangoBook has more info on it: http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222